# VS2015 Enable DirectX debug messages in output for Universal Windows apps

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, directx, message

I have created a DEBUG device in my DirectX11 application, which would normally make the messages show up in the output window. Now it doesn't though and I have no clue on how to enable it...

Question: How do I enable verbose DirectX debug messages in the output window?
Context: Writing an UWP app in C# using DirectX11 through SharpDX.

Edit: It might not be Visual Studio at fault, can Universal Apps get DirectX debug messages at all?

Comment: What do you mean by output window? Is it the VS output pane? Have you enabled "Enable native code debugging" in the "Debug" tab of your project properties? Also, what do you expect for the debug? Because if you are using the API correctly, you won't get any debug message.

Comment: Yes I mean the VS output pane. I expect to at least see the object creation/destruction to be shown (info/verbose messages). The check mark "Enable native code debugging" has been removed on the Universal App platform it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Use mixed mode debugging. You can enable it in project properties debug tab.

[image: Mixed mode debugging]

Comment: I tried this, seems to slow down a bit and throw a load of C++ exceptions (EETypeLoadException). No DirectX messages though...

Comment: Make sure to create D3D11 device with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag. EETypeLoadExceptions you're seeing are first chance exceptions that are safe to ignore. You can uncheck the checkbox "break for this exception type" when such exception gets through, so they will continue silently next time.

Comment: I do have that flag, well the C# equivalent of it anyway. SharpDX is basically 1:1 API wrapper.

Comment: So are you sure that the output is just not showing up, versus there's nothing outputed? Did you try calling ID3D11InfoQueue::AddApplicationMessage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to manually output a message and see whether it shows up?

Comment: I followed your suggestion, I think I did it right (device.QueryInterface<InfoQueue>().AddApplicationMessage(MessageSeverity.Information, "Another attempt")) - But there's no output in the VS output pane...

Comment: Is that also the case if you do MessageSeverity.Error? By default, MessageSeverity.Info is not printed at all.